# Check if div has html elements inside

Tags: jquery

I was just wondering how can I check if a div has no children because I need to place a placeholder text if the element does not load into the specified div.

Here is my code:

```
var test = ($('#'+chartId)).children().length;
console.log(test);
if(test==""){
    alert('empty');
}
else{
    alert('present');
}
```

Will this work if I'm trying to detect if a flash component is being loaded to a div?

Comment: Why don't you try it and ask if it doesn't work??

Comment: You don't need to convert the length to a string. Just `if($("#id").length)` will do. And yes, `children()` will only return HTML children so you should be safe using that

Answer (score 5):

.length is 0 and not empty when there are no childrens. Also you can shorten your code a bit, like so:

```
if(!($('#'+chartId)).children().length){
    alert('empty');
}
else{
    alert('present');
}
```

Comment: But `0 == ""` is true, and that is the test he was using. Not best practice, but equivalent to what you have.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
if($('#' + chartId).children().length > 0){
    alert('present');
}
else{
    alert('empty');
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EYSLM/3/)

Comment: if are inside a div or a tag yes you can count it @a_miguel6687

Comment: how about if its inside an <object> tag?

Comment: I have update my demo, try now with object @a_miguel6687

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you're making is comparing length (a number) to an empty string. If there is nothing and you call `.length` on it, it will return 0, not empty string.

```
var length = $('#one').children().length;
if (length > 0) {
    alert('hi');
}
if (length === 0) {
    alert('bye');
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/349Uq/

Comment: Will this work with an swf object element? It does not seem to work for me

Comment: Yes it was already working the problem was that because I put the condition in the callback which is wrong since assuming that flash is not present in the browser